# How to get data from QR scanner in android kotlin

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I'm scanning data from the QR code in Android camera opens for scanning but it is not providing the scanned data.

I use these libraries and give Camera permission and camera hardware-feature.

**implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0'
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.2.0'**

Here is my code in a fragment:

```
private fun startQRCodeScanning() {
  val integrator = IntentIntegrator(activity)
  integrator.setPrompt("Scan QR Code")
  integrator.setOrientationLocked(false)
  integrator.setTorchEnabled(true)
  integrator.initiateScan()
}
```

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
  val result: IntentResult? = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (result != null && result.contents != null) {
         txtScannedData.text = result.contents
        }  
  }
```

How can I solve this problem?